# Connect Tomcat with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm trying to connect Tomcat with Eclipse but it seems some errors happen.
I have tried many ways like change the directory path to fix this error but still the same.
It's very nice if someone can help me to solve this problem. Thanks all.

Here is an image of my problems.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdmSt.png)

Comment: You probably don't want to use anything installed into Program Files because of permissions. Try letting it download a fresh copy for you.